# Kendo for .net Core 3.1

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, razor-pages

I try to use Kendo in my Razor Pages app, I followed this doc https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/first-steps, but I have error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Kendo.Mvc.Rendering.IKendoHtmlGenerator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Kendo.Mvc.Rendering.KendoHtmlGenerator': Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ClientValidatorCache' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.)'

I'm using Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core, version 2019.1.220.

Comment: The error sounds like an interface is registered with a DI container, however, during resolution, there is no class that implements the interface.

Comment: You may need a more recent version of Kendo for .NET Core 3.1 support. I believe that wasn't officially available from kendo until the R3 2019 version of Kendo (which is later than the version you're using)  https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-core-ui/r3-2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add my comment as an answer, because [this Telerik thread](https://www.telerik.com/forums/could-not-load-type-%27microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-internal-clientvalidatorcache%27) confirms (and references the same error you are encountering) that you'll need a later version of Kendo to have support for .NET Core 3.1.

This quote here from the thread linked above - about .NET Core 3.0 requiring a later version than you are using:

> Artem, that is correct. Only the latest version of the UI for ASP.NET
> Core suite (2019.3.1023) offers official support for .Net Core 3.0.
>
> Jerry, feel free to contact us if you have any further questions on
> the .Net Core 3.0 integration.
>
> Regards, Veselin Tsvetanov

[R3 2019 is the first release](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-core-ui/r3-2019) that mentions full support for .NET Core 3.1.